# I'm trying to loop for a positive integer, but I keep getting exceptions in the main method even though I'm using a try-catch

Tags: java

Here's my code:

```
public static double[] getArrayInput() {
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    int arrayLength;
    double[] arrayInput;
    try {
        System.out.print("Please enter the length of the array: ");
        arrayLength = stdin.nextInt();
        while (arrayLength <= 0) {
            System.out.print("Invalid input, please enter a positive integer: ");
            arrayLength = stdin.nextInt();
        }
        }
     catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.out.print("Invalid input, please enter a positive integer: ");
        arrayLength = stdin.nextInt();
    }
    arrayInput = new double[arrayLength];
    System.out.print("Please enter the array elements: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        do {
            double j = stdin.nextDouble();
            arrayInput[i] = j;
        } while (arrayInput.length < arrayLength);
    }
    return arrayInput;
}
```

I need to be able to continuously prompt for an integer value if a non-integer is entered. I read online that you can use the scanner.hasNextInt() method to do this, but every time I try to implement it, I keep getting new exceptions in my main method.

Should I expect for an exception to go to my main method if I have a catch block in this method?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @sidgate Originally it was an InputMismatchException but recently I've been getting a NegativeArraySizeException in the main method as well when I try to use the hasNextLine() method.

Comment: My main method is mostly calls to other methods. Here it is:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did notice the problem and is marked here in the complete program:

As you will notice you will need to do `stdin.nextLine()` to skip the last invalid input from being read again by the scanner.

Other than that, there is a bit of refactoring to your code.

```
  public static double attemptInputElement(Scanner stdin) {
    try { 
      double j = stdin.nextDouble();
    } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
      System.out.print("Invalid input, please enter a valid element");
      stdin.nextLine(); // skip the last input
      attemptInputElement(stdin);
    }
    return 0.0; // should never get reached.
  }

  public static double[] getArrayInput() {
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    int arrayLength;
    double[] arrayInput = null;
    System.out.print("Please enter the length of the array: ");
    try { 
      arrayLength = stdin.nextInt();
      while (arrayLength <= 0) {
        System.out.print("Invalid input, please enter a positive integer: ");
        arrayLength = stdin.nextInt();
      }
    } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
      System.out.print("Invalid input, please enter a positive integer: ");
      stdin.nextLine(); // skip the last input
      arrayLength = stdin.nextInt();
    }
    arrayInput = new double[arrayLength];
    System.out.print("Please enter the array elements: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
      do {
          arrayInput[i] = attemptInputElement(stdin);
      } while (arrayInput.length < arrayLength);
    }
    return arrayInput;
  }
```

Comment: THANK YOU! You have no idea how grateful I am! I just could not get this and I really appreciate you showing me my mistakes. Now I'll be sure not to repeat them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

catch(Exception e)
{
  //catch all exceptions here
}

That way it won't go to Main.

Next, it seems un-necessary to have two loops just to fill in the array elements. And you also probably want to have a try/catch around that nextDouble()

Comment: Why doesn't what I have now keep the exception from going to the main method? I really don't get exception handling I guess. Also, thanks for spotting the possible issue with nextDouble().

Comment: Because the class type of the exception thrown does not match what you have in the catch, therefore, it skips it and throws it out of the function until someone catches it. Every exception is derived from Exception so it catches everything because InputMismatchException is a Exception. Exception is at the highest level and everyone else derives from it.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. Sorry, I actually did know that but I guess after frustratingly messing with a problem all day things can get by you. Thanks, I appreciate the help!